# Resizing a control in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, resize

I have a set of user controls in my wpf form and want to give ability to user to resize them. Whenever a user clicks on a control total 8 boundary rectangles should appear and then by dragging any of them, the user must be able to resize the control. Please help me on this.

Comment: Simpler solutions to the resizing issue can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834452/resizing-textbox-at-runtime-in-wpf

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to build a Resize Adorner. If you google it thou shallt find!
http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!144.entry
Don´t know if that´s the best sample around, but it´s a good start anyways!
/Simon

Answer (score 2):

I made [a library](https://gitlab.com/rr789/wpf-resize-adorner) that applies resize grips to any control.

[image]

Homepage has a quick gif video showing it in-action.

Very simple, just call one line of code.

```
//Set max resize to 200px max height, 300px max width.
new CResizeAdorner(button1, 200, 300);
```