# C# WPF Resizing issue

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I am working on a dashboard application where I would like to let the user resize the widgets on a canvas. Looking around, the best solution to me seemed to use Microsoft's ResizingAdorner class. The example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771714.aspx) and the code can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples) (About a quarter way down the page). Everything seemed to work until I clicked one of the widgets (chart controls from [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/)). The bottom right [adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx#about_Adorners) and the top right [adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx#about_Adorners) seemed to appear about the width of the and height from the side of the canvas when ever moved. See example below :

[image]
[image]

I have been to the StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834452/resizing-textbox-at-runtime-in-wpf) about using a grid splitter, but this will not work for me since controls will be overlapping grid columns.

I also have been to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771275/resizing-a-control-in-wpf), but the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771275/resizing-a-control-in-wpf/771361#771361) does not work at all, and the second [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771275/resizing-a-control-in-wpf/771360#771360) just merely points to a [blog](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/) where the gentleman either works for microsoft and created the ResizingAdorner class or just copied the code from the wpf samples site. I have also tried is revised code [here](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/the-wpf-resizing-adorner-for-canvas/) but with no luck. 
**Is there a quick fix i'm not seeing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking into the code a little deeper, I found a portion that was subtracting the x and y from the desired width and height, even thought I wasn't dragging the adorner yet. so I changed the following code in their example :

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            // desiredWidth and desiredHeight are the width and height of the element that's being adorned.  
            // These will be used to place the ResizingAdorner at the corners of the adorned element.  
            double desiredWidth = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
            double desiredHeight = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;
            // adornerWidth & adornerHeight are used for placement as well.
            double adornerWidth = this.DesiredSize.Width;
            double adornerHeight = this.DesiredSize.Height;

            topLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            topRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            bottomLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            bottomRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));

            // Return the final size.
            return finalSize;
        }
```

to the following code:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            // desiredWidth and desiredHeight are the width and height of the element that's being adorned.  
            // These will be used to place the ResizingAdorner at the corners of the adorned element.  
            double desiredWidth = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
            double desiredHeight = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;
            // adornerWidth & adornerHeight are used for placement as well.
            double adornerWidth = this.DesiredSize.Width;
            double adornerHeight = this.DesiredSize.Height;

            //Orginal Microsoft code
            //topLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            //topRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - (adornerWidth / 2), - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            //bottomLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            //bottomRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - (adornerWidth / 2), desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));


            topLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            topRight.Arrange(new Rect(adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            bottomLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            bottomRight.Arrange(new Rect(adornerWidth / 2, adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));

            // Return the final size.
            return finalSize;
        }
```

I haven't experienced any quirks yet, but it seems right.