# Implementing a resize grip on WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the user to be able to re-size ScrollViewer controls in my WPF application. I'm creating the ScrollViewer controls at runtime, so the resize grip needs to be implementable via the c# code.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Resize_Control_at_Runtime.aspx) may be a solution but i don't understand Visual basic thus i cant understand of it

[Screenshot of my application.](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g324/thezaza101/ResizeGrip.jpg)
I need a resize grip on the light-green box(Which is a ScrollViewer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is this what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771275/resizing-a-control-in-wpf)?

Adorners were meant for things like this. The article you are referring to looks like WinForms to me...

Comment: O wow, how did i not find that >.< searched for nearly 2 hours